# Develop an android app which would stream audio and play it on client's mobile

Tags: android

I want to develop an android app which would stream the audio files made by me and play them. I want to know how to stream these audio files to client's mobile. This is my first app. So i have little knowledge of android app development. Also do i have to build a music player also in the app?

Comment: As written this question's pretty broad. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am currently trying to develop a high level architecture. I am thinking of using aws to store the audio files and stream them to client on request.